# Ktor reified type parameter

Tags: kotlin, generics, ktor

I created class with generic in kotlin and want to use receive with generic, but I have error when i want to `call.receive` type from generic:

> Can not use MType as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.

Code:

```
class APIRoute<EType : IntEntity, MType : Any> {
    fun Route.apiRoute() {
        post {
            val m = call.receive<MType>()
            call.respond(f(model))
        }
    }
}
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the expected type to the `receive()` function. Due to [type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure) in Java/Kotlin, the type of `MType` is unknown at runtime, so it can't be used with `receive()`. You need to capture the type as `KType` or `KClass` object when constructing `APIRoute`.

`KClass` is easier to use, however it works with raw classes only, it doesn't support parameterized types. Therefore, we can use it to create e.g. `APIRoute<*, String>`, but not `APIRoute<*, List<String>>`. `KType` supports any type, but is a little harder to handle.

Solution with `KClass`:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val route = APIRoute<IntEntity, String>(String::class)
}

class APIRoute<EType : IntEntity, MType : Any>(
    private val mClass: KClass<MType>
) {
    fun Route.apiRoute() {
        post {
            val m = call.receive(mClass)
            call.respond(f(model))
        }
    }
}
```

Solution with `KType`:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val route = APIRoute.create<IntEntity, List<String>>()
}

class APIRoute<EType : IntEntity, MType : Any> @PublishedApi internal constructor(
    private val mType: KType
) {
    companion object {
        @OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)
        inline fun <EType : IntEntity, reified MType : Any> create(): APIRoute<EType, MType> = APIRoute(typeOf<MType>())
    }

    fun Route.apiRoute() {
        post {
            val m = call.receive<MType>(mType)
            call.respond(f(model))
        }
    }
}
```